# Mostrar registros validando dos campos en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy realizando la siguiente consulta en una Base de Datos:

```
SELECT t1.uid, t2.mail, t3.field_nombres_value, t4.field_apellidos_value, t5.field_telefono_value, t6.field_celular_value, t7.field_origen_registro_value

FROM users_roles t1

LEFT JOIN users t2 ON t1.uid = t2.uid
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_nombres t3 ON t2.uid = t3.entity_id
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_apellidos t4 ON t3.entity_id = t4.entity_id
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_telefono t5 ON t4.entity_id = t5.entity_id
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_celular t6 ON t5.entity_id = t6.entity_id
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_origen_registro t7 ON t6.entity_id = t7.entity_id

WHERE t1.rid IN (5, 8, 11, 14) AND t5.field_telefono_value IS NOT NULL
```

La cual me arroja los datos de los usuarios, excepto los que tengan `NULL` en el campo teléfono.

Yo necesito traer todos los registros excepto los que tengan NULL en el campo teléfono o en el campo celular, hay registros que nada más tienen uno de los campos y esos registros me interesan mostrarlo.

¿Como hago para validar eso?

Comment: Si la arme yo, la consulta con todos los campos me arroja un total de 203.805 registros, con la condición del field_telefono_value IS NOT NULL me arroja solo 17.934 pero hay registros donde el teléfono es NULL pero el celular no y ese registro si me interesa mostrarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el `WHERE` debes agregar la condición tal y cómo la planteas utilizando operadores lógicos:

```
WHERE /-- tus cláusulass. como tu t1.rid que no se que es--/
    AND (t5.field_telefono_value IS NOT NULL 
        OR t6.field_celular_value IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Tenés razón, no me di cuenta

Comment: Hay gente que critica o juzga y otra que colabora. Si llegamos a esta comunidad es porque tenemos dudas, de igual, gracias por tu comentario Marcos.

Comment: @JoseDarioCorrea, mi intención era ayudarte a que lo resuelvas solo. No era mala leche. Como ves la solución era simple, ya la habías escrito en tu pregunta, solo faltaba aplicarla en la consulta.